# Output localized urls in navigation

Tags: url, localization, navigation

Does `{{ url('handle') }}` output the right url for localized sites?

I have a fr/en site and both lang output the english paths, but shows the right content and language/strings on the page.

I'm a bit confused. How do you guys build your navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `{{url('handle')}}` will output the correct URL for whichever localization your user is currently in. Be sure to adjust your `siteUrl` configuration in your `app/config/general.php` file. Depending on your set up, it can look something like this:

```
return array(
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en' => 'http://mysite.com/en',
        'fr' => 'http://mysite.com/fr'
    )
);
```

For more information, check out [Step 4 in the Localization Guide](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide#step-4-define-your-site-uRLs).